# Change std::thread execution flow with signals in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, signals

I have a program starting an std::thread doing the following: sleep X, execute a function, terminate.

```
create std::thread(Xms, &func)
  wait Xms
  then do func()
  end
```

I was wondering if I could for example send a signal to my std::thread in order to instantly break the sleep and do func, then quit.

Do I need to send the signal to std::thread::id in order to perform this?

my thread is launched this way, with a lambda function:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void                          execAfter(T func, U params, const int ms)
{
  std::thread                 thread([=](){
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(ms));
      func(params);
    });
  thread.detach();
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: why are you waiting in the first place?

Comment: @stefan I am actually implementing the bombs in a bomberman game, and they explode after x time, and I am looking to implement a "chain reaction" between bombs explosions. If a bomb explosion collide another bomb, she have to explode instantly and not wait for Xms to explode.

Comment: It's possible, but difficult. 'C++ Concurrency in Action' (ch. 9.2) spends a full 10 pages on sketching an implementation and discussing its pitfalls (which I'm not going to replicate here). If Boost is an option, consider using boost::thread instead which ships with [interruptible threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption).

Comment: @Mayerz I see. It doesn't seem appropriate to me that every bomb gets its own thread. I'd suggest a concurrent (or at least thread-safe) BombHandler that either lets the bombs explode by timeout or proximity of another explosion. Thread creation is rather expensive, so I would avoid doing it for every bomb.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Can't use Boost sadly, school project. :(

Comment: @stefan Well I agree with you, but for now changing it looks hard, so I will try it after current version work. SO if we could just find a solution to this i would be glad. But you are right, I just get aware of this after coding the whole thing :/

Comment: I only have a kind of ugly solution involving std::condition_variable, give me a minute to write it down as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `wait_for` of `std::condition_variable` would be the way to go, if the thread model can't be changed. In the code snippet below, the use of the condition_variable is wrapped into a class of which objects have to be shared across the threads.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

class BlockCondition
{
    private:
        mutable std::mutex m;
        std::atomic<bool> done;
        mutable std::condition_variable cv;
    public:
        BlockCondition()
        :
           m(),
           done(false),
           cv()
        {
        }
        void wait_for(int duration_ms)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
            int ms_waited(0);
            while ( !done.load() && ms_waited < duration_ms )
            {
               auto t_0(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());
               cv.wait_for(l, std::chrono::milliseconds(duration_ms - ms_waited));
               auto t_1(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());
               ms_waited += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t_1 - t_0).count();
            }
        }
        void release()
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);
            done.store(true);
            cv.notify_one();
        }
};

void delayed_func(BlockCondition* block)
{
    block->wait_for(1000);
    std::cout << "Hello actual work\n";
}

void abortSleepyFunction(BlockCondition* block)
{
    block->release();
}

void test_aborted()
{
    BlockCondition b();
    std::thread delayed_thread(delayed_func, &b);
    abortSleepyFunction(&b);
    delayed_thread.join();
}

void test_unaborted()
{
    BlockCondition b();
    std::thread delayed_thread(delayed_func, &b);
    delayed_thread.join();
}

int main()
{
    test_aborted();
    test_unaborted();
}
```

Note that there *might* be spurious wakeups that abort the wait call prematurely. To account for that, we count the milliseconds actually waited and continue waiting until the done flag is set.

Comment: This looks great actually! Think I am gonna use this. Is that fair to change the owner of the reward?

Comment: Accepting an answer is a personal choice and you may change it as often as you'd like. To avoid that someone feels pissed, you shouldn't do this very quickly. Take your time to decide what helped you the most.

Comment: Dats right, I will take time to digest yours but it looks interesting. WIll put the green check as soon as I have used it ok?

Comment: Your `m2` mutex will get you into trouble if destroying the `BlockCondition` without calling wait() first. Also, you *will* get spurious wakeups on all architectures which do require them (e.g. every architecture relying on [ll/sc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-Link/Store-Conditional)).

Comment: @ComicSansMS Thanks for pointing that out, I've adjusted the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out in the comments, this wasn't the smartest approach for solving your problem in the first place. As implementing a proper interruption mechanism is quite complex and extremely easy to get wrong, here are suggestions for a workaround:

Instead of sleeping for the whole timeout, simply loop over a sleep of fixed small size (e.g. 10 milliseconds) until the desired duration has elapsed. After each sleep you check an atomic flag whether interruption was requested. This is a dirty solution, but is the quickest to pull of.

Alternatively, supply each thread with a `condition_variable` and do a `wait` on it instead of doing the `this_thread::sleep`. Notify the condition variable to indicate the request for interruption. You will probably still want an additional flag to protect against spurious wakeups so you don't accidentally return too early.

Comment: Thanks for this answer mates, I have to discuss it with my crew. Looks like we are in deep shit :)
I will maybe reconsider my bomb system.

Comment: @Mayerz This is a dirty, dirty hack.  Better hope nobody is looking to closely at the code!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to figure this out I found a new implementation, it's inspired by all your answers so thanks a lot.

First I am gonna do a BombHandler item, in the main Game item. It will have a an attribute containing all the Bomb items.

This BombHandler will be a singleton, containing a timerLoop() function who will execute in a thread (This way I only use ONE thread for xxx bombs, way more effective)

The timerLoop() will usleep(50) then pass through the whole std::list elements and call Bomb::incrTimer() who will increment their internal _timer attribute by 10ms indefinitely, and check bombs who have to explode.

When they reach 2000ms for instance, BombHandler.explode() will be called, exploding the bomb and deleting it.

If another bomb is in range Bomb::touchByFire() will be called, and set the internal attribute of Bomb, _timer, to TIME_TO_EXPLODE (1950ms).

Then it will be explode 50ms later by BombHandler::explode().

Isn't this a nice solution?

Again, thanks for your answers! Hope this can help.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable solution. Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: _The timerLoop() will usleep(50) ... and ... will increment their internal _timer attribute by 10ms_ Expect premature bomb explosions :)

Comment: @InnocentBystander you necromancer! Usleep(50) is 50ms rigth?

Comment: @Mayerz, usleep(50) is 50 microseconds, which is equivalent to 0.05 milliseco... **KABOOM**

Comment: @InnocentBystander ok thanks guys. Anyway this was a school project I did years ago! I am working now, but thanks for the memory!

Comment: Practical example of Einstein's Theory of Relativity :)